# Declarar array dentro de bucle vs vaciarlo en cada vuelta

Tags: c++, c, array, rendimiento

Me pregunto si en C/C++ es mejor declarar un nuevo array a cada vuelta de los bucles:

```
while(true) {
  char array[255] = "";

  // Hacer algo con el array ...
}
```

O vaciarlo a cada vuelta del mismo:

```
char array[255] = "";

while(true) {
  for(short i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++) {
    array[i] = 0;
  }

  // Hacer algo con el array...
}
```

Por *mejor* me refiero tanto desde una perspectiva de rendimiento (velocidad) como de buenas prácticas.

Comment: `array[i] = "";` eso no compila, en todo caso es `array[i] = 0;`

Comment: Cierto, @rnd, corregido. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En lo que se refiere a buenas prácticas, lo mejor sería declarar la variable en el ámbito más pequeño/restringido que puedas (en este caso dentro del bucle si no se va a usar fuera en ningún sitio). Hace el código más fácil de mantener (p.e.: no tienes que subir 100 líneas para ver con qué tipo se inicializó la variable x) y en algunos casos el compilador podría aplicar algún método de optimización.

Ahora desde el punto de vista de rendimiento, va a depender en gran medida del compilador (y el lenguaje) que utilices y tendrías que hacer pruebas para comprobar cuál es mejor. Los compiladores modernos se encargan de [optimizar el código generado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilador_optimizador), por lo que el resultado debería ser muy parecido (si no igual) en ambos casos.

---

...Esa era la teoría, ahora vamos a ver la práctica. He creado tres casos de prueba (aunque quizás no de la manera más científica) con bucles que se repiten 10 millones de veces y los he ejecutado 20 veces para ver los resultados. Éste es el código:

Caso 1: declaración dentro del bucle

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < 10000000; x++) {
        char array[255] = "";
        array[0] = (char) (65 + (x%23));
        //printf("%s\n", array);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Caso 2: Declaración fuera del bucle, vaciado con bucle for

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    char array[255];
    for (x = 0; x < 10000000; x++) {
        int y;
        for (y = 0; y < 255; y++) { 
            array[y] = 0;
        }
        array[0] = (char) (65 + (x%23));
        //printf("%s\n", array);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Caso 3: Declaración fuera del bucle, vaciado con memset

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char array[255];
    int x = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < 10000000; x++) {
        memset(array,0,255);
        array[0] = (char) (65 + (x%23));
        //printf("%s\n", array);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Y los resultados fueron (redoble de tambor):

- Caso 1 - 0.1587 segundos
- Caso 2 - 6.1470 segundos
- Caso 3 - 0.1413 segundos

Lo cual es un poco ******** porque tira por tierra <s>toda</s> parte de la teoría que puse arriba. Para el primer y tercer caso sí se cumpliría, pero no para el segundo caso (seguramente hice algo mal... o tengo el peor compilador del mundo que también es bastante posible).

Comment: Esa es la respuesta que yo quería dar, 100% de acuerdo. Tu teoria es cierta, pero un bucle dentro de otro bucle siempre será más lento, memset esta implementado ensam y es un caso especifico de llenar todo con 0, eso de por si es una condición muy especifica del compilador para generar código muy optimizado.

Comment: El caso 2 es más lento simplemente porque itera 250.000.0000 de veces, mientras los otros iteran simplemente 1.000.000 de veces. Esas diferencias de tiempo no tienen nada que ver con la ubicación de la declaración.

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta, muchas gracias! Me apunto `memset` para futuras referencias, buen apunte.

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que la complejidad será lineal y el proceso de reserva de memoria e inicialización igual de costoso o con costes parecidos por cada vuelta del bucle; pero es dífícil de evaluar ya que el compilador puede tomar decisiones para optimizar el código.

Parece que estás frente a un caso de optimización prematura ([early optimization en inglés](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)):

> Los programadores desperdician una cantidad enorme de tiempo pensando o preocupandose sobre el rendimiento de partes no críticas de sus programas, y estos intentos de mejorar la eficiencia en realidad tienen un fuerte impacto negativo respecto a la depuración y mantenimiento del programa. Debemos olvidarnos de las pequeñas eficiencias.

Si consideras que esa parte del código es crítica, mi consejo es que hagas pruebas con diferentes opciones de optimización del compilador usando una y otra opción, nunca seremos más listos que el compilador... incluso código que podemos haber escrito de manera *ineficiente* el compilador puede traducirlo a algo de mayor rendimiento entre bambalinas. Apuesto que incluso en el peor de los casos tu arreglo de 255 elementos no supondrá un cuello de botella en el rendimiento de tu programa y el compilador hará un buen trabajo optimizando dicho código.

#### Editado:

Por otro lado, depende del uso que le vayas a dar a `array`, puedes saltarte el paso de inicialización:

```
while(true) {
    char array[255];

    // Hacer algo con el array ...
}
```

Si no le asignas valor al array éste no será inicializado a 0 y por lo tanto, será un proceso menos a hacer en cada vuelta del bucle (no pagues por lo que no usas, este es un principio de C++). Esto será útil si lo primero que haces con `array` es escribir en el, de manera que su información previa no es relevante... incluso podría ser un motivo para que el compilador reutilice el espacio de `array` en cada vuelta en lugar de crearlo de nuevo.

Comment: `char array[255]` no parece precisamente un array de longitud variable.

Comment: Por otro lado, para arreglos de longitud fija, como es el caso, sería recomendable usar `std::array` en vez de `std::vector`

Comment: No es un ALV, he escrito demasiado rápido. Y si, `std::array` sería la elección correcta, asumí que era ALV por eso sugerí `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Las buenas prácticas indican que lo recomendable es que el ámbito de las variables sea el mínimo posible. Esta recomendación pretende evitar la reutilización de variables para fines diferentes.

En términos de rendimiento parece obvio deducir que obligar al programa a reservar e inicializar X bytes de memoria en cada iteración de un bucle va a ser más costoso que reservar una vez e inicializar en cada iteración del bucle.

Ahora bien, el rendimiento suele ser un tema controvertido. En el ejemplo que propones, ¿Se puede considerar importante el tiempo que va a emplear el sistema en reservar 255 bytes en cada arreglo? La respueta final depende de los requisitos del algoritmo. Si, por ejemplo, esta función va a tardar medio segundo y únicamente se ejecuta cuando el usuario presiona un botón se puede considerar tranquilamente que el tiempo es despreciable... si en cambio el tiempo es una unidad crítica y el resto del algoritmo está super optimizado la cosa cambia.

Mi recomendación es que primero te preocupes de crear código legible y, una vez terminado, comrpuebes si es necesario optimizarlo o si con lo que tiene cumple con las especificaciones.

Por cierto, para incializar memoria puedes hacer uso de `memset` en vez de crear tu propio bucle.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que tener en cuenta que crear una array local a la función es trivial para los compiladores en la mayoría de los casos, puesto que se trata de un simple ajuste del tamaño de la pila.

En muchas arquitecturas, ajustar el tamaño de la pila ocupa muy pocas instrucciones en código máquina, y **no accede a memória**. El simple hecho de 'limpiar' un array con `array[0] = 0` puede implicar ese temido acceso a memória ( depende del uso del array dentro del bucle, de forma que los últimos accesos hagan que `array[0]' esté dentro de las líneas de caché del procesador ).

El curioso valor obtenido al *limpiar* el array mediante `memset()` es posiblemente debido al compilador. **gcc**, por ejemplo, implementa `memset()` mediante código máquina generado *inline*, sin realizar ninguna llamada a función real alguna. Esto, junto con sus propias optimizaciones, será el responsable de tan inesperada velocidad.

Comparándolo con el caso de `array[0]=0`, aquí si que *obligamos* al compilador a generar código; por mucho que se optimicen, los compiladores aún no saben programar ellos solos ;-)

Reconozco que la velocidad al usar `memset()` me sorprendió.